# How to generate access_token after user credential is validated?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, access-token, asp.net-apicontroller

I have no idea how to start in the block after credential is validated.

```
        if (member_username == "//username" member_password == "//password")
        {
            //what should i do here?
            //can i use any existing method to generate access_token?
            result.isSuccess = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result.isSuccess = false;
        }
```

Comment: Why not just ASP.Net Identity for authentication ?

Comment: Do you have any reference for me? Hope i can get some idea from it. I tried to read the basic authentication but still not really understand.

Comment: Kindly read this tutorial to better understand Identity http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ this also explains how to use /Token